# Use truetype Comic Sans font in XeTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex

I want to test truetype comic sans fonts in xetex, the following codes are modified from source of [free-math-font-survey](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/free-math-font-survey):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Comic Sans MS}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Theorem 1 (Residue Theorem).}
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated singularities $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$ then
\[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k) \text{Res}(f;a_k).\]

\textbf{Theorem 2 (Maximum Modulus).}
\emph{Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then}
\[\max\{|f(z)|:z\in G^-\}=\max \{|f(z)|:z\in \partial G \}.\]
\vspace*{-1em}

\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\ABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\newcommand{\alphabeta}{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\varkappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi o\pi\varpi\rho\varrho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega}
\newcommand{\AlphaBeta}{\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}

$\mathrm{A} \Lambda \Delta \nabla \mathrm{B C D} \Sigma \mathrm{E F} \Gamma \mathrm{G H I J K L M N O} \Theta \Omega \mho \mathrm{P} \Phi \Pi \Xi \mathrm{Q R S T U V W X Y} \Upsilon \Psi \mathrm{Z} $  $ \quad 1234567890 $

{\par \tolerance=0 \emergencystretch=100em $a\alpha b \beta c \partial d \delta e \epsilon \varepsilon f \zeta \xi g \gamma h \hbar \hslash \iota i \imath j \jmath k \kappa \varkappa l \ell \lambda m n \eta \theta \vartheta o \sigma \varsigma \phi \varphi \wp p \rho \varrho q r s t \tau \pi u \mu \nu v \upsilon w \omega \varpi x \chi y \psi z$ \linebreak[3] $\infty \propto \emptyset \varnothing \mathrm{d}\eth \backepsilon$\par}

\end{document}
```

I get the following result[image]

While the result in the above document is [image]

The problems are: (1) alphabat characters inside math formulas are not typeset in Comic Sans font, and (2) some math symbols are missing. How to resolve these problems?

Comment: You will be struck by various thunderbolts by typographs here for using Comic Sans ;-)

Comment: +1 for the aim of teaching high math to 5-year-olds. _/sarsasm_

Comment: Other than that, there's the package [`mathastext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext?lang=en) which helps to use the text font even in math mode. However, I think it is not a good idea. Preparing a proper math font is more than just taking some glyphs somewhere and using them for typesetting math. For instance, Comic Sans misses the blackboard letters completely that you use for the complex field.